# How to property set a routers base URL for URL generation

Tags: base-url, aurelia

I'm using [pushState](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/2) for routing and my page is served from `www.mydomain.com/thepage`. Appropriate routes look like `www.mydomain.com/thepage/home`, `www.mydomain.com/thepage/user/{userId}` etc.

Accordingly, I've set the `base` tag in my index file and the routers `config.options.root` to `/thepage`.

Everything is working as expected (routing, generated links for router views etc.).

Only dynamically generating new route URLs from code or the [templating router](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router) does not adhere to my base URL:

**Use templating router within view**

```
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <a route-href="route: user; params.bind: { userId: user.id }">
    <!-- ... -->
</template>
```

**Manually generate route from code**

```
let url = router.generate('user', { userId: id });
```

Both approaches result in the erroneous URL `www.mydomain.com/user/12` where the base URL part `thepage/` is missing.

By debugging the `router.generate` method, I've discovered that the router has a seperate `baseUrl` property, which produces the correct output, when set:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    // ...
    router.baseUrl = '/thepage'; // <-- Manually set baseUrl
    config.options.root = '/thepage';
    config.map([
        // The routes...
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

I'd really appreciate some insight on the following questions:

1. Why do I have to set the `baseUrl` property in the first place when there's already the `root` config option? What are the differences?
2. Why do I have to set it on the router itself, whilst other configurations are typically performed on the `config` object in Aurelia?
3. Is this approach valid? I'm not quite sure if I'm supposed to do it this way since the `baseUrl` is not mentioned in the [Articles & Guides](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/1) secion of the Docs but only in the [Library API](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/1.2.1/class/AppRouter) where it is only described with `The [[Router]]'s current base URL, typically based on the [[Router.currentInstruction]].`.

Comment: Did you find an answer / solution? I find myself in the exact same situation. Even updating config.options.root inside the child router does not seem to be mentioned anywhere I could find

Comment: See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-router/issues/57

Comment: Sorry just realized that the mentioned GitHub issue actually covers a different issue. No, I have no further information so far. Please let me know if you find out more!